# Why does this produce an error if I use self to define a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code with `a=5` it works fine, when I run it with `self.a=5` I get the error NameError: name 'self' is not defined. Why?

```
class yes:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello yes")
    self.a=5 #produces an error

class yes:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello yes")
    a=5 #works fine
```

Comment: class variable vs. instance variable

Comment: Because `self` is not defined. It works like any other argument to a function, that it, it is a local variable to the function

Comment: I'm confused - I thought that the self variable "refered to the object itself". So if the self variable refers to the object I thought it would be local to the class definition (which defines the object) and not the method definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable as a class member, not an instance member, so there is no `self` in scope. If you indent `self.a=5` to be within the `__init__()` body it will work as I think you hope it should